# MongoDB won't insert document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't know what I am doing wrong, however the following is not working.

I have the database connecting however when I try and use the connection it won't let me.

index.js

```
config = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mDB = require('./components/mongodb').connect(config.dbUri);
app.get('/testDB', (req,res) =>{
  const user = { name: 'John', age: 30 };

  mDB.insertOne(user, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Successfully inserted user: ${result.insertedId}`);
    res.send("inserted");
  });

});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000');
});
```

./components/mongodb.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports.connect = (uri) => {
  MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`);
      process.exit(1);
    }

    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
    module.exports.client = client;
  });
};

module.exports.insertOne = (collection, document) => {
  module.exports.client.db('PodToo').collection(collection).insertOne(document, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Successfully inserted document: ${result.insertedId}`);
  });
};
```

I get the `Successfully connected to MongoDB`

But then when I try and use it I am receiving

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertOne')
```

Comment: omg, you've never answered a question on SO that wasn't your own?

Answer (score 1):

In the danger of stating the obvious: You are missing the first argument to your insertOne function, the collection name.

Did you mean

```
mDB.insertOne('users', user, ...
```

?